# Everything is way off in IE7 & IE8

Tags: css, xhtml

It's just insane, I've made soo many websites and still it seems every time IE7 and IE8 behave differently every time!!

I'm working on a friends website: [Class One](http://www.classone.org)

Except I can't seem to get my head around why IE7 and 8 seem to be adding in **extra spacing.** The **positioning** of the text overlay div on the jquery slider is off a few pixels and wont cover the full width and the inner div float left content just looks way off, why wont it meet the float right, the maths is right!

I would normally attach code if I knew the problem area but It would be an awful lot of css and html to attach so just put the link up instead.

Thanks in advance!

**P.S. I am aware of the php error code, I am getting the hosting provider to sort that as I type! :)**

Turns out the php warning is before the doc type so this maybe it?

Comment: I would get the PHP error code sorted out before anything else; it's appearing before your DOCTYPE, which might well be confusing IE into working in quirks mode, thus completely confusing the issue.

Comment: You'll also need a reset stylesheet to iron out the differences between user agent stylesheets.

Comment: Yup I never realised the error was being placed before the doc type! bugger, Thanks for that. And Yi Jiang. I never use reset stylesheets I find they cause more problems and confusions. I too used to doing work arounds for IE already! :)

Comment: You are using ids instead of classes. Why are using
*#inner #innerwrap #feed* instead of just *#feed*

edit: I'd make a suggestion, but your css says "You do not have the rights to edit this file without express permission from Pretty Klicks"

Comment: Diadem, I am Pretty Klicks. The reason I do this is because id's are for one off elements and classes are able to be applied to more than one element. I use the correct css selectors as it stops any confusions when coding and for the browser. I used to find that I would have conflicting style parameters and end up having to use !important an awful lot. This way is more clearer and accurate. It gives you more control in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major problem here is the [DOCTYPE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp).
This tag must be the first tag in you code, but isn't, because of the PHP Warning.
See:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mkdir() [<a href='function.mkdir'>function.mkdir</a>]: Permission denied in <b>C:\Program Files\HSphere\3rdparty\PHP\PHP5\prepend.php</b> on line <b>33</b><br />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Change beginning of output to

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

---

If you don't put this tag in the first line, IE will activate `quirks mode`, and very strange things will happen. When a browser activate [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html), many things change, as [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html).

NOTE: many browsers has quirks mode, not only IE (I know that firefox has too).

---

Note: correct use of DOCTYPE will reduce the differences between IE7 and IE8, but not remove all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Ever heard of the IE box model? It's so fun.

Here's some info:
http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2007/09/12/ie-and-the-css-box-model-wronger-than-wrong/

Summary of IE hacks found to deal with your problems:
http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/ie7-dehacker.html

Differences in IE 8:
http://www.evotech.net/blog/2009/03/ie8-css-support/

Comment: Yeh I've been making websites for 8 years, I know the box model stuff and the problems it poses in IE and it's bugs. I usually find a work around through trial and error however it appears the answer above got it, I didnt realise the error was confusing IE.... thanks anyway